# "R cannot be resolved to a variable " in android Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

i  was doing small android application  ,  i added  blank xml file but it was showing some error although i did not add any code and still it was showing error so i cleaned project but now after cleaning for my activity  when i write

```
setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
```

its giving errors like  this `R cannot be resolved to a variable`    , 
for another  activity named `ReminderListaActivity` i tried this

```
setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit)
```

`error was for xml file not for "R "`  error was  :`reminder_edit cannot be resolved or is not a field`  .

xml file is in layout and its showing like never used file  so how do i  solve this issue ,  can someone help me with it  pleae

**EDIT**  code added

reminder_edit.xml

```
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
        <EditText 

            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/body"
             />
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="5"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:gravity="top" /> 

        <TextView 
           android:text="@string/date"

           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/reminder_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Reminder_Time"
            />

        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/remindertime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remindertime"
            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**java File**

```
public class ReminderEditActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
    }

}
```

Comment: please post the xml and by the way clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: The `R` class is constantly generated. This can't happen if your XML files contain errors. Sadly not all errors preventing generation are shown. If no error is shown look at your recent changes very carefully and search for invalid (in the sense of the Anrdoid SDK) content.

Comment: Just in case, your edit_reminder.xml file is located in the res/layout folder, right?

Comment: @Joy yes that is in res/layout and  there is no error in xml

Comment: To make sure there are absolutely no xml errors (copy your R file and put it on your desktop or somewhere to keep) go ahead and delete your R file, if it gets generated the problem is somewhere else, if it doesn't then there is a problem in one of your xml files.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the errors in XML so the resource compiler can generate `R.java` for you.

Comment: there is no error in xml , i cleaned project and   not its ok ,but tihs is hte issue  came after cleaning

Comment: Have a look at the Console tab, looking for error messages from the resource compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Remove **Import android.R;** from imports in your activity class

Comment: please upload your complete main class for more help.

Comment: Try...right click project->properties->android->project build target->select target and apply changes

Answer (score 2):

In order to accesst "R.layout.edit_reminder" xml file you must import your "R" file which is found under the "gen" folder. This file is automatically generated, so you can go ahead and delete it and it will be generated again. Now, if you have **any** xml errores whatsoever the R file won't be generated, that's a sign that you have to look to your xml to find the problem.

In regards to the import, you'll find them on your **Activity** Class, at the very top right after the **package declaration**.

Make sure that the R you are **importing** is:

```
yourpackage.R;
```

rather tahn

```
android.R;
```

When writing code quickly at times **android.R** gets imported and you don't even notice. That's the first thing I always check, it's happened to me a couple of times already.

Next thing I would suggest doing is looking to see your **console** and **problems** view (if these are not set in your perspective, then go to Window>Show View>Other and select the appropriate ones).

Look for something along the lines of **Error with xml file aborting build**. Look for what xml file it is talking about, and then look for errors in it.

Comment: i dont import any android.R (can you clear your point pleas i am new to android ) this import is not there in my java file

Comment: If this was the problem, the error message would be different. It's a common problem, though.